# what does this notation mean? (Polynomials as vector space)

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, quotient-spaces

Let *V*$=\mathbb{F}[x]$, determine if the quotient space *V/W* is finite dimensional when *W*$=x^nV$. Is $W$ the space when multiplying every polynomial by $x^n$?

Also is the answer to that question finite dimensional because I can construct a basis $\{V,x+V,...,x^{n-1}+V\}$ for $V/W$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $x^n V$ means $\{x^n v: v \in V\}$.  And yes, that is a basis.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your understanding is correct.